# how to merge cells both column and row wise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, axlsx

```
  sheet.merge_cells 'H3:U3'
  sheet.merge_cells 'H3:H5'
```

Does not work. First i need to merge columns (H3:U3) then merge it rowwise (H3:H5) to get big rectangle cell. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

solution is WAAAAAAAAY too simple

```
sheet.merge_cells 'H3:U5'
```

gem does everything under the hood itself